# How to delete special characters from a string in Java?

Tags: java

Following is my code and I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

```
import java.io.*;

class Replace
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        StringBuffer S1;
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        S1=br.readLine();
        String result=S1.replaceAll("[<>,.]","");
        System.out.println(S1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: @J_mie6 the code doesn't even compile...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: and the compiler is pretty explicit about what does not, and why.

Comment: Error messages from the compiler contain important information to help you solve the problem. Read and try to understand the error message. Include the exact error message in your question here.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I hadn't taken a proper look at it, only noted that he didn't post what the actual error he was getting was and asked for it! :)

Answer (score 4):

1. `BufferedReader#readLine()` returns a `String` not `StringBuffer`. Change the type of `S1`. Also, choose a better variable name.
2. You're storing the string replaced with special characters in `result`, but you're printing `S1`.

Comment: Apart from these, looks like OP wants/needs to sanitize the String. There are libraries to do this instead of doing this job manually...